# Можно ли прочитать rtf документ средствами php ?

Tags: rtf, php

Ребята, можно ли подключиться удаленно на хости и прочесть ртф докумет что бы вывести у себя, это реально ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/678192/is-it-possible-to-display-an-rtf-file-inside-a-web-page-using-php

Comment: Я сделал как вы написали: http://puu.sh/1xG4A  но у меня при открытие страницы выдает сохранить файл или открыть его локальной прогрммой, я сделал что то не так ?

Comment: А когда я его читаю через file_get_contents и отдаю - то выходят просто много кракозябр (

Comment: нннет :) я вам дал ссылку на похожий вопрос. Посмотрите ответ, который отмечен как правильный. Там решение вашей проблемы

Comment: почему то не работает, другие варианты есть ?

Comment: Что не так ?

$zas ="http://gorodkuzneck.ru/download/doc1_text_17_14260_programmana2012.doc";

$html_output_path = ''
$html_output_filename = $username . $timestamp;
if ($zas)
{
  shell_exec('rtf2html ' . 
    escapeshellarg($zas) . " " .
    $html_output_path . $html_output_filename);
}
$html_to_display = file_get_contents($html_output_path . 
  $html_output_filename);

Comment: потому что doc, а не rtf

Answer (score 2):

Прочитайте статью [Текст любой ценой: RTF](http://habrahabr.ru/post/70119/), там весьма доходчиво объяснено как парсить rtf посредством PHP. Заодно увидите примерный исходный код.

Если ищите готовый класс, то попробуйте воспользоваться [готовым](http://rob.lensen.nu/devdoc/phpdivinglog/__filesource/fsource_phpdivinglog__includesrtfclass.php.html) классом.

ЗЫ: Напоследок несколько полезных ссылок: [rtf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_Text_Format) (на английской википедии), текст стандарта [rtf 1.9.1](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=10725).